# Samsung Sm-A500H: Google Play reports "This app is incompatible with all of your devices"

Tags: applications, google-play-store, samsung

How can I install an application which was previously installed on my device? I have a Samsung Sm-A500H.

I want a way how to do this without rooting.

Google play-store always says

> "This app is incompatible with all of your devices."

Comment: There's a probability that the version on the Play Store drops the support for your device. May I know what's the app that you want to install?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to be rooted to do this. You can try to search the application file on google. You have to accept installation from unknown sources in the security option menue in your phone settings before. 
Just search for "Your desired APP name.apk" - make sure to grab a relativly new version of it and try to install it manually.

But to be clear: Don't download any paid app this way. Also: This file may modified in some way so do this at your own risk. Updating it via the PlayStore won't work too. I hope this helps you.